# Internet Explorer 11 fantastically lying about pixels

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On http://quizdash.co.uk/  Internet Explorer got HUGE error: it scaling site content to all screen, but in develepment panel, it say that content not scaled and has original size.

http://storage2.static.itmages.com/i/16/0201/h_1454300006_8737908_ad9e854b85.png

Of course, scale option=100%.

Other browsers show site correctly.

Is this undocumented feature of modern IE? Can I with css/html make IE do not scale site?

Comment: .... what is the question again?

Comment: @VicenteCunha quiestion fixed =)

Comment: On Chrome I'm seeing `183x323`, I don't understand the issue

Comment: @AlexeiDarmin m? Chrome and Firefox show site correctly. Internet Explorer scale site, but tell us (in dev panel), that site not scaled. This is issue.
Did you try open it in IE?

Comment: Perhaps your IE is zoomed in by accident. Dev panel would show the native size of the element regardless of what zoom level you have. Try `cmd ctrl +` or `cmd ctrl -` (for mac) or `ctrl +` or `ctrl -` (for windows) until you are viewing at `default 100%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error in IE or an undocumented feature.

In your vendor.css, the following CSS appears:

```
@-ms-viewport{width:10in;zoom:1;initial-scale:1;max-zoom:1}

@-o-viewport{width:10in;zoom:1;initial-scale:1;max-zoom:1}

@viewport{width:10in;zoom:1;initial-scale:1;max-zoom:1}
```

That's causing the page to scale with the viewport. The only browsers that support `@viewport` are IE and Opera Mini, so the page will only scale in those browsers. As far as the CSS is concerned, the page is displaying correctly in IE, not the other browsers, so your assertion that the other browsers are showing the site correctly is wrong. However I cannot comment on whether IE is "lying" about computed pixel sizes because I don't know how or if viewport scaling should affect computed values.

If you don't want the page to scale with the viewport, don't use `@viewport`.

Comment: Thanks! This helps me:

```
@media screen {
    @-ms-viewport {
        width: device-width;
    }
}
```